# Probability- counting problem

Tags: probability

4 friends wash separately cars. At the end they have washed together 37 cars. How is the distribution among the four friends possible? How is the distribution if they each have at least 5 cars washed?

Comment: In reality there is likely to be a difference between counting and probability.

Comment: This question is definitely going to get down-voted. It is unclear, in particularly, the `how the distribution is possible` part. In addition, no thoughts, attempts or general effort to solve it yourself are shown whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds as though you are asking "In how many ways can four distinct friends wash 37 distinct cars (if each car is washed by only one of the friends and all cars are washed)."  Assuming that the order in which the cars are washed doesn't matter, ask the questions:

- Who washed the first car?
- Who washed the second car?
- ...
- Who washed the $n^{th}$ car?
- ...
- Who washed the $37^{th}$ car?

Convince yourself that in answering each of those questions in a specific way, it *uniquely* determines a different scenario.  Apply multiplication principle to complete the problem.

To answer the second half of the question, apply inclusion-exclusion to avoid the scenarios where a friend has fewer than five cars that they washed.

---

In the case that the cars are considered identical, this becomes equivalent to the question of "How many Dionphantine solutions exist for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 37$ with $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$"

This is solved via *Stars-and-Bars*.  Imagine three barriers (described with a $-$ symbol), and 37 stars (described with a $\star$ symbol).  Each car will be represented by a $\star$, and the stars to the left of the first $-$ will be washed by the first friend.  The stars inbetween the first and second $-$'s will be washed by the second friend, etc...  So: $\star\star - \star - \star - \star\cdots$ corresponds to the first friend washing two cars, the second washing one car, the third washing one car, and the fourth friend washing all of the rest.  How many ways can you arrange 3 $-$'s and 37 $\star$'s?

To complete the second part of the problem, before beginning give each person five cars to wash ahead of time.  Now there are 17 cars still needing to be washed.  Determine the number of ways of distributing these 17 cars without restriction in the same manner as before.  In the terms of a Dionphantine equation, treat it as a change of variable that $y_i = x_i-5$ and $y_i\geq 0$ for each $i$ and $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = (x_1-5)+(x_2-5)+(x_3-5)+(x_4-5) = 37 - 20 = 17$

There does exist a useful notation for the stars and bars problem:  $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{r}\!\!\right)$ is the "multichoose" function, defined as $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{r}\!\!\right) := \binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$